# How to pass an stored procedure result to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a table that will populate from different stored procedures. Each stored procedure is to populate a specific table.

This is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @i int = 28878

DECLARE @ptj01 AS numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ptj02 AS numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ptj03 AS numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ptj04 AS numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ptj05 AS numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ptj06 AS numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ptj07 AS numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ptj08 AS numeric(18,2)

SET @ptj01 =
(
    EXEC [dbo].[SEL_Saint_Contar_Visitas] @idpre = @i
)
```

What I need is that `@ptj01` stores the value returned from the stored procedure `SEL_Saint_Contar_Visitas` which returns a numeric value so that then, I can:

```
SELECT
    @ptj01 as [Pt01],
    @ptj02 as [Pt02],
    .
    .
    .
etc...
```

But I'm getting a syntax error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

EDIT: this is the code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEL_Saint_Contar_Visitas]
    (@idpre int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        IIF ((SELECT COUNT(*)    
              FROM [dbo].[CYM_Impresiones] [I]
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion] [P] ON [P].[UsrIp] = [I].[IpRef]
              WHERE ([P].[ID] = @idpre)) < 1, 1,
                (SELECT COUNT(*)    
                 FROM [dbo].[CYM_Impresiones] [I]
                 INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion] [P] ON [P].[UsrIp] = [I].[IpRef]
                 WHERE ([P].[ID] = @idpre)))
```

Comment: You use an [output parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: what's inside your sproc?

Comment: @Uueerdo that's quite untrue. There are 3 things you can (easily) consume for a Stored Procedure; the first result first, the `OUTPUT` parametees (which there can be many) and the `RETURN` value (normally reserved to denote the success of the Procedure).

Comment: Given the code in your SP doesn't actually do anything other than a `select`, it probably makes more sense to put the query inside a function.

Comment: @Larnu True, I the return values completely slipped my mind; most of the procs in the project I work on do not make use of that feature.

Comment: The return result is intended as as status indication, and can only be an int - so won't work if you need a decimal value as your SP indicates.